# Bitnami Umbrella chart - a subchart for multiple application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am using helm bitnami charts for my application to deploy in kubernetes.

My application contains following 3 components,

Web UI
Web API 1
Web API 2
Here Web UI is the static UI application in nginx server and the Web API 1 and Web API 2 are the aspnet core web API application called in Web UI application.

Currently deploying like below,

The Web UI using nginx chart - https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/nginx

```
helm install web-ui-dev bitnami/nginx
```

The Web API 1 using aspnet-core chart - https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/aspnet-core

```
helm install web-api1-dev bitnami/aspnet-core
```

The Web API 2 also using same aspnet-core chart

```
helm install web-api2-dev bitnami/aspnet-core
```

Since my application is dependent on 3 components, i am planning to use the helm umbrella chart.
So created a parent chart (say 'ag') with below dependencies in chart.yaml file and in values.yaml giving all the subchart values.

```
dependencies:
    - name: nginx
      version: 6.2.0
      repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    - name: aspnet-core
      version: 0.2.0
      repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

But the problem here i could not use the aspnet-core chart to deploy both Web API 1 and Web API 2 in a single helm install command of umbrella chart.

When i say helm install dev ag its not installing all 3 components, either i can deploy Web API 1 or Web API 2.

Any idea to make this work of using the single helm install of umbrella chart to deploy multiple applications of same chart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use alias in your dependencies file. like this.

```
    - name: nginx
      version: 6.2.0
      repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    - name: aspnet-core
      version: 0.2.0
      repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
      alias: web-api1-dev
    - name: aspnet-core
      version: 0.2.0
      repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
      alias: web-api2-dev
```

Then use aliases in your main values.yaml file.

Comment: it works, thanks. I have 1 more chart which is not hosted in repository. Any idea how to use that same chart.tgz file as dependent for multiple app.

Comment: you can use file path for this instead url. keep your charts in same folder same repo etc.



```repository: file://../.../your_chart_folder
```

Answer (score 2):

Please reffer to the [Helm Documentation](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#chart-dependencies).

Adding an alias for a dependency chart would put a chart in dependencies using alias as name of new dependency.

One can use alias in cases where they need to access a chart with other name(s).

> Currently deploying like below...The Web UI using nginx chart, the Web API 1 using aspnet-core chart, the Web API 2 also using same aspnet-core chart

Additionally documentation provides insight on `tags` and `condition` so you can enable/disable charts installation (so potentially split your  APIs)